# How can I differentiate a 0 from false in a map?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdmap

I encountered the following problem:

After I erase a key and a call the key once again from the map, it always returns 0.

So what if the value of a certain key was set to 0?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  std::map<std::string, int> mymap;

  mymap["a"] = 10;
  mymap["c"] = 10;
  mymap["b"] = 20;
  mymap["zero"] = 0;

  if (mymap["zero"])
    std::cout << "yes" << '\n';
  else
    std::cout << "no" << '\n

    mymap.erase("zero");

  if (mymap["zero"])
    std::cout << "yes" << '\n';
  else
    std::cout << "no" << '\n';


  std::cout << mymap["zero"] << '\n';


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But I'm not storing `false`, the `if` condition is checking if there exists a value for the "zero" key.

Comment: In that case, you don't get a `true` or `false` from your map. You get an `int` and it's converted to `bool`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is the [`count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count) function.  `count()` will return the number of elements and won't construct an object if it doesn't exist.  That would make your if statements look like

```
if (mymap.count("zero"))
    // key exist here
```

---

Since you can use C++17, if you want to do something to the element if found you can leverage it's new if statement syntax that allows you to declare a variable in the if statement and have

```
if (auto it = mymap.find("zero"); it != mymap.end())
{
    // the element exists and it points to it
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 3 seconds! Clearly I shouldn't have added that `...` at the end :p

Comment: @scohe001 lol.  I was really surprised.  I hit post and all of the sudden your answer appeared.

Comment: The `count` solution has a very minor drawback that if you ever change the type of `mymap` to an associative container that allows duplicates it will silently increase the complexity while `find` will not.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux True.  But in the case of the non multi containers I like it better as it is less typing.  Good point though.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `if(mymap["key"])` to check if key exists, use [`.count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count):

```
if(mymap.count("zero")) { //key exists!
    ...
```

Your issue here is that the [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) will create a new key/value pair if one doesn't exist. From cppreference:

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.

So if you try to use `mymap["zero"]` to tell if the key `"zero"` exists in your map, of course it will--you're creating it!

Answer (score 3):

`operator []` of map will insert a new entry with default value. You should use `find` instead:

```
if (mymap.end() != mymap.find(std::string{"zero"}))
```

Comment: So we now have 2 answers for find, and two answers for count. ))

Comment: I would endorse `find` over `count` because it gives you a useful iterator if you do want to check the value. To retrieve the value after a call to `count` would be to perform two lookups instead of one.

Comment: @alterigel this is why I always use find and never used `count` in my life on a non-multimap. On the other hand, in the given example OP doesn't use the found value, so `count` provides for shorter notation.

Comment: @SergeyA indeed, but it looks like OP is also just starting to learn about `map` and should be aware of `find`, and also get comfortable with the end iterator idiom

Answer (score 2):

There are several options. The easiest one is to check for presence of an element using `std::map::find`, rather than `operator[]`, which always creates a default value if it is not there.

The other option is put `std::optional` as a map data type, and than check if the optional is set.